# How to prove that the sequence (${x_n}$) converges and calculate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

- Sequence (${x_n}$) is defined by formula ${x_1} =\sqrt{a} ,{x_2} =\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}},...,{x_n} = \sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+...+\sqrt{a}}}$  n-roots,a>0.

So fare i have prove that the sequence (${x_n}$) is monotone ascending but i don't now how to prove that (${x_n}$) is restricted above and how to calculate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)$

Comment: Just a guess: $\;a\ge0\;$ , right?

Comment: Yes i have forgot to mention it

Answer (score 4):

**Proof:** the sequence given by $x_1=\sqrt{a}$, $x_2=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}$ and so on fulfills the recurrence relation
$$ x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+x_n} \tag{1}$$
and is clearly an increasing sequence. Let $\xi$ be the only positive solution of $x=\sqrt{a+x}$, namely $\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$. We may notice that $x_n<\xi$ implies $x_{n+1}<\xi $, since:
$$ x_{n+1} = \sqrt{a+x_n} < \sqrt{a+\xi} = \xi\tag{2} $$
Due to $x_1<\xi$, it follows by induction that $x_n<\xi$ for any $n\geq 1$.
Now, since $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is an increasing sequence, bounded above by $\xi$, it is a converging sequence, with $L=\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n = \sup_{n\geq 1} x_n$. Due to the continuity of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{a+x}$, the limit $L$ has to fulfill
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n = L = \sqrt{a+L} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt{a+x_n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_{n+1} \tag{3}$$
and since $L>0$, $L=\xi$ and we may state:
$$ \sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{\ldots}}}}=\color{red}{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: I completely understand how you found the limit of the sequence, however can you give extra help how to prove that the sequence is restricted above

Comment: @SeadMejzini: we have that $\xi=\sqrt{a+\xi}$. Assume that $x_n<\xi$ and you have $$\color{red}{x_{n+1}}=\sqrt{a+x_n}\color{red}{<}\sqrt{a+\xi}=\color{red}{\xi}.$$ It follows that $x_1<\xi$ implies $x_n<\xi$ for every $n$.

Comment: As I can see here we are using the fact that $ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_{n\:}\right) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\cdot a}}{2}$ , but first we should prove that the sequence converges. This mean that we can't use the fact $ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_{n\:}\right) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\cdot a}}{2}$ to prove that the sequence is bounded above or I misunderstand somewhere

Comment: No, I am not assuming it converges, I am proving it. I will rewrite my answer soon to make it more clear.

Comment: @SeadMejzini: answer restyled.

Comment: @jackd'aurizio, Shouldn't $(3)$ read $\lim x_n$ instead of $\lim a_n$?

Comment: @AOrtiz: sure, fixed.